# Comparing files using vector space model

Tags: python

I have to create a demo using vector space model in Python based on the following problem:

1. We have a set of texts in different files.
2. Compare texts on the basis of word density.
3. You have to create a script to compare texts in the files and find out :

(I).  Which files have similar texts
(ii). Put similar files in a group  [ for example:    GROUP_1(  FILE25, FILE65 ) ]

---

Note:   One file may be added to multiple groups
I mean one text can be similar to more than one group

I currently have the following code:

```
      import filecmp
      files = ['F1.txt', 'F2.txt', 'F3.txt', 'F4.txt', 'F5.txt']
      comparisons = {}
      for itm in range(len(files)):
         try:
             res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+1])
             comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+1])] = res
             except:
             pass
         try:
             res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+2])
             comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+2])] = res
            except:
            pass
         try:
             res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+3])
             comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+3])] = res
            except:
            pass
         try:
             res = filecmp.cmp(files[itm], files[itm+4])
             comparisons[str(files[itm]) + ' vs ' + str(files[itm+4])] = res
            except:
            pass
  print(comparisons)
```

This gives:

```
{'F1.txt vs F2.txt': True, 'F1.txt vs F5.txt': False, 'F2.txt vs F4.txt': True, 
'F3.txt vs F4.txt': False, 'F1.txt vs F4.txt': True, 'F2.txt vs F3.txt': False, 
'F2.txt vs F5.txt': False, 'F1.txt vs F3.txt': False, 'F3.txt vs F5.txt': False, 
'F4.txt vs F5.txt': False}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply CountVectorizer ..  you will get the vector now
2. Apply euclidian distance or cosine similarity on two vectors to compare

For above two steps  there are readymade functions in sklearn. just explore the library

Alternatively you can simply use fuzzywuzzy to. It compares using EditDistance (Rather than vector space), but the results are good in many cases.